# Sharing bin folders between different ASP.NET projects

Tags: asp.net, bin-folder

Does anyone know if it's possible for multiple projects to reference/share the same bin folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all of the DLLs are in the same "bin" folder, multiple apps can be run from within the same IIS application.  To IIS, this just looks like a single application because there is a single "bin" folder.

This probably shouldn't be done unless you have a good reason, though.  You lose process isolation and make the deployments harder.

Answer (score 0):

I normally have a Library folder in my project root then link all of the projects in the solution to the same dll via the Browse tab under 'Add Resource'.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about what you actually want to do here.  Say you manage to set this up and you wind up with three projects, all referencing assembly B in one place.

You have to make a 'breaking' update to assembly B to satisfy a requirement for one of those projects, but you don't have time to update the other two to suit.  What do you do in this situation?

Comment: All projects will have the same requirements. That is why we want to use the same bin folder to save space.

Comment: @Hoang - Why three different projects then?  Why not a single project, multiple virtual directories pointing at the same files and, I imagine, some way of skinning the front end according to which URL you come in on.

Comment: we are looking to add sub-sites programatically and the cms tool we are using only allows adding a new project which then creates new files and folders for each project (bin folder is big enough that it will become a problem once it gets big enough). Not sure how to go about creating virtual directory programmatically and how to refer to the project. Thanks.